# Typescript type inference from enum throws "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite."

Tags: typescript

I have a scenario where I want to map an enum to a type such that the user could call a function and based on the enum passed into the first parameter it can infer the type for the second parameter.

I have set it up as follows:

```
enum MyEnum {
  One,
  Two
}

interface OnePayload {
  one: string;
}
interface TwoPayload {
  two: string;
}

type FuncPayload<T> = T extends MyEnum.One
  ? OnePayload
  : T extends MyEnum.Two
  ? TwoPayload
  : any;

const func = <T extends MyEnum>(key: T, payload?: FuncPayload<T>) => {
  return payload;
};
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
func(MyEnum.One,{one: 'a'}); // OK
func(MyEnum.Two,{one: 'a'}); // Throws type error
func(MyEnum.Two,{two: 'a'}); // OK
```

This works well except that in my example I have 100~ enum values that I want to map to their respective types. Once I added that many conditions to the `FuncPayload` type it began throwing the `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.` error whenever I use that type.

Is there a) a better way to accomplish this? or b) a way to get around this error using this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that worked:

```
enum MyEnum {
  One,
  Two
}

interface OnePayload {
  one: string;
}
interface TwoPayload {
  two: string;
}

interface FuncPayloadMap {
  [MyEnum.One]: OnePayload;
  [MyEnum.Two]: TwoPayload;
}

const func = <T extends MyEnum>(key: T, payload?: FuncPayloadMap[T]) => {
  return payload;
};
```

I guess you can map each enum value to an interface using an interface and then just use a your generic type to reference the correct interface in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) and [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) instead, so that you won't need to actually pass in an enum type?

```
interface PayloadA {
  one: string;
}
interface PayloadB {
  two: string;
}

function isPayloadA(object: PayloadA | PayloadB): object is PayloadA {
    return (object as PayloadA).one !== undefined;
}

function myOperation(payload: (PayloadA|PayloadB)) {
  if (isPayloadA(payload)) {
    // payload is now strongly typed as PayloadA
  }
}
```

I guess it ultimately depends on what you're trying to accomplish. What is your `func` function supposed to do? Strongly cast a loosely typed object?

Comment: I want the enum, it's not just for typing. Essentially it's a command executor, and the enum is which command to execute and the payload should be typed accordingly.